# Firebase Hosting Rewrite URL

Tags: firebase, redirect, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

is there any way to rewrite this URL in firebase.json ?

http://localhost/api/**whatever**/product.json

to become

http://localhost/api/product.json

**whatever** means any kind of path, so I expect if we insert that **whatever** path, then the browser will not redirect to 404 but redirect to

http://localhost/api/product.json

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a pretty regular rewrite with a glob pattern as far as I can see. Based on the documentation on [Firebase Hosting rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) it should be something like:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "**/product.json",
    "destination": "/api/product.json"
  }]
}
```